# Fast insert unique container

Tags: c++, multithreading, collections

I posted the same question at StackOverflow then I got an advice to post it here.

Original question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998297/fast-insert-unique-container

I have to store elements (struct State) in a 2D vector container and each element must be unique.

I store the elements like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>>> m_container;
```

And I have an insert function

```
bool insert(State && value, std::size_t deepness);
```

Which should inset 'value' into m_container[deepness] if the value is unique or the new deepness is smaller then the previous in which case I have to remove the previous State (return true is inserted).

I have multiple threads inserting at the same time, I already have an implementation but I not sure if it is the best so I am interested in a better and faster way for the insert or some improvements.

My implementation is rather long so I try to shrink it down while keeping the logic behind it.

other than the container I have multimap:

```
std::multimap<std::size_t, std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> m_multimap;
```

key: hash of the state

pair_1: deepness

pair_2: the position of the State in m_container[deepness]

I have a lockless_queue of struct Temp (lockless_queue m_queue) I insert here first then to the container.

```
template<typename T>
class lockless_queue {
public:
    // storeing the elements
    struct node;
    struct node_ptr;

    // insert element
    template<typename... Args>
    void produce(Args&&... args);
    void produce(T && data);
    void produce(const T & data);

    // consume all elements form queue
    node_ptr consume_all();

    // queue is not empty
    operator bool() const;
};

struct Temp {
    std::unique_ptr<State> value;
    std::size_t hash;
    std::size_t deepness;
    bool exist = false;

    Temp(State * v, std::size_t hash, std::size_t deepness, bool exist);
    Temp(State && v, std::size_t deepness);

    Temp move() {
        return Temp(value.release(), hash, deepness, exist);
    }

    bool is_equal(const State & state) const;
    bool is_equal(State * state) const;
    bool is_equal(const Temp & other) const;
    bool is_equal(Temp * other) const;

    void swap(State && v, std::size_t d) {
        deepness = d;
        value.reset(new State(std::move(v)));
    }
};
```

The following function is the insert function which inserts to the locless_queue

```
bool pre_emplace(State && value, std::size_t deepness) {
    Temp temp(std::move(value), deepness);
    const auto range = m_multimap.equal_range(temp.hash);
    if (range.first == range.second) {
        m_queue.produce(std::move(temp));
        return true;
    } else {
        const auto & container = m_container;
        const auto it = std::find_if(range.first, range.second, [&temp, &container](const auto & iter) {
            return temp.is_equal(container[iter.second.first][iter.second.second].get());
        });
        if (it == range.second || deepness < it->second.first) {
            temp.exist = true;
            m_queue.produce(std::move(temp));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(some case the return true is invalid because the queue is not unique but it is not a problem, I only use the return value for estimating the number of inserted elements)

this function consumes the elements from the queue into a temporary multimap of hash and Temp

```
void m_finalize_cycle(std::multimap<std::size_t, Temp> & multimap) {
    auto head = m_queue.consume_all();
    auto node = head.ptr;
    while (node) {
        if (!node->data.value) { node = node->next;  continue; }
        auto & temp = node->data;
        const auto range = multimap.equal_range(temp.hash);
        if (range.first == range.second) {
            multimap.emplace(temp.hash, temp.move());
        } else {
            const auto it = std::find_if(range.first, range.second, [&temp](const auto & pair) {
                return temp.is_equal(pair.second.value.get());
            });
            if (it == range.second) {
                multimap.emplace_hint(range.first, temp.hash, temp.move());
            } else if (temp.deepness < it->second.deepness) {
                it->second.value.reset(temp.value.release());
                it->second.deepness = temp.deepness;
            }
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

and this function load all Temp value from the previous multimap into m_container

```
void m_finalize_write(std::multimap<std::size_t, Temp> & multimap) {
    for (auto &[hash, temp] : multimap) {
        if (temp.exist) {
            const auto range = m_multimap.equal_range(temp.hash);
            auto & container = m_container;
            const auto it = std::find_if(range.first, range.second, [&temp, &container](const auto & iter) {
                return temp.is_equal(container[iter.second.first][iter.second.second].get());
            });
            if (it != range.second) {
                m_container.at(it->second.first).at(it->second.second).reset(nullptr);
                m_multimap.erase(it);
            }
        } else {
        }
        // extend m_container
        extend_if_needed(temp.deepness);
        m_container.at(temp.deepness).push_back(std::move(std::unique_ptr<State>(temp.value.release())));
        m_multimap.emplace(hash, std::make_pair(temp.deepness, m_container[temp.deepness].size() - 1));
    }
}
```

while I insert elements I run the m_finalize_cycle in every 10 microseconds then if I finished with the inserts I call the m_finalize_write.

This implementation works fine for me but unfortunately, it is the slowest part of my code so I am interested in better ways.

Edit:

I might skipped some important details:

struct Temp hold additional information which makes it a bit slower to create than the simplified version, this information is used in temp.is_equal() function so it slows down the comperation between Temps as well.

```
struct State {
    State * partent; // parent is not hashed    
    std::pair<int8_t, int8_t> data;
    std::array<std::pair<int8_t, int8_t>, N> more_data;
};

bool Temp::is_equal(const State & state) const {
    if (!value) return false;
    if (value->more_data != state.more_data) return false;
    if (value->data == state.data) return true;


    // this last line where I use the additional information 
    // field is a 2D array it can be generetad from State and is_reachable function compere the cell value with a const value 
    // (field[data.first][data.second]) >= X);
    return field->is_reachable(state.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## more speed

You can find [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) of Stroustrup explaining why `std::multimap` is so slow<sup>※</sup>.  See [*Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)* by Matt Austern](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf).

Use Boost.Container for [flat_(multi)map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) which is a mature implementation based on Matt’s article, via Andrei Alexandrescu.

As a drop-in replacement, see what that does for your speed!

---

```
multimap.emplace_hint(range.first, std::make_pair(temp.hash, temp.move()));
```

That can (now) be written much more simply:

```
multimap.emplace_hint(range.first, { temp.hash, temp.move() } );
```

---

```
if (node->data.value == false)
```

Testing a bool against true/false is just strange.  It *is* a bool; use it.

```
if (!node->data.value)
```

---

```
while (node != nullptr)
```

Don’t explicitly test against `nullptr`.  Use the the truth value of the pointer’s value, which might (in the case of smart pointers) be an efficient `operator bool` in the class.

```
while (node)
```

---

## addendum

**※** A flat map wins for *looking things up*, which in my experience is the bulk of the run.  The tree-based map will start beating flat-map for inserts and deletes at some size n and continue pulling ahead since the k<sub>1</sub>∙O(log n) is a better order than k<sub>2</sub>∙O(n) even when k<sub>2</sub> is much smaller than k<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: boost::container::flat_multimap was slower than the std::multimap by a large margin, I insert elements in cycles with multimap I inserted 2 million elements in 65 seconds  40 cycles and with flat_multimap I inserted 600000 elements in 105 seconds 25 cycles (with std::mulimap the 25th cycle took 1.33 sec), I implemented the other small changes.

Comment: @Sekkmer very interesting… what compiler and std library are you using?  Hmm, the node version is good for **inserting** and deleting, which is what you tested, and gets stronger with larger count.  The flat version is good for **looking things up** without incurring multiple cold cache hits.

Comment: @ JDługosz I use Visual Studio 2017 with std:c++latest and all optimization turned on, I here is a picture of [CPU/RAM usage of my program](https://imgur.com/a/vY6ntvx?) the low CPU load is when I have to wait on "m_finalize_cycle" and at the end when some memory is freed "m_finalize_write" the high CPU load is when I generate new States with multiple threads, (m_finalize_cycle) is running at the whole operation